# Function to count number of common vowels in two strings

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghci

So I am trying to create a function such that it prints the number of common vowels between the given strings for example

common vowels "Hello Joe" "Nice to meet you" would output =2 as "o" and "e" are the common vowels. I don't have much of an idea how to do this.

My code at the moment looks like:

```
c_vow :: String -> String -> Int
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
c_vow xs ys  = length [x | x <- xs ++ ys, x `elem` vowels]
```

Comment: Can you solve either of these two easier subproblems? 1. Print all of the vowels in a given string 2. Given two lists, print all of the elements that are in both of them

Comment: Yeah so I have been able to change the code to print all the common vowels: 
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
c_vow :: String -> String -> Int 
c_vow xs ys  = length [x | x <- xs, x `elem` vowels, y <- ys, x==y]
This code prints total instances rather than just the number of common vowels so using the same example as above it now prints 7 rather than the require output of 2.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348145/function-to-count-number-of-common-vowels-in-two-strings#comment129537252_73348145) is quite close. You should only avoid enumerating over the string, such that for each match, it will pick that value.

You can do so by enumerating over the `vowels`, and using [**`elem :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) twice to check if that vowel appears in both strings:

```
vowels :: [Char]
vowels = "aeiou"

c_vow :: String -> String -> Int
c_vow xs ys = length [ v | v <- vowels, v `elem` xs, v `elem` ys]
```